# Find words in text by start and stop characters

Tags: c#, regex

I need to find and replace all words in text.
Format of these words : 
start with `(long)`, end with `;`
example

```
(long)Row["Id"];
```

whats is the regexp pattern for this format ? I tried some but dont works for me.
Thanks.

Comment: What do you want to replace them with ? What have you tried so far ?

Comment: replace to Row["Id"].ToLong(); first i must find all words in this format. i trid simple ^ and $ regexp char with different combinations ex : ^(long);$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
var input = "(long)Row["Id"];";
var result = Regex.Replace(input, @"\(long\)([^;]+)", "$1.ToLong()");
```

The following expression: `\(long\)([^;]+)`:

- `\(`: Matches an open parentheses `(`.
- `long`: Matches the word long literally.
- `\)`: Matches a closed parentheses `)`.
- `([^;]+)`: Matches one or more non-semicolon characters and puts them into capturing group 1.

Answer (score 2):

```
\(long\)(.*?);
```

`(.*?)` generally tries to capture as many as necessary to find the `;` at the end. And as for the `(long)` you will need to escape the parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to regex, you can use [`String.StartsWith`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.startswith%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`String.EndsWith`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.endswith%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) methods.

For example;

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\Public\TestFolder\Text.txt");            
foreach(string word in lines)
{
   if (word.StartsWith("(long)", StringComparison.InvariantCulture) && word.EndsWith(';', StringComparison.InvariantCulture))
   {
      //Replace your string here.
   }
}
```